# Input not being put in through out Vector

Tags: c++, string, vector

Okay, So i am trying to read input into a vector, then print it out in reverse order.
I have a pretty good Idea of how to do that ( I think) but my problem is that my code only reads user input into the first slot of the vector. . . I need it to read 10 separate strings from input into 10 different slots in my vector. . . here is what I've got so far:

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <vector>;
#include <string>;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> name_list(11);
    int n = 0;
    for (int n = 0; n < 11; ++n);
    getline(cin, name_list[n]);
    cout << name_list[0];

    int stop;
    cin >> stop;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a semicolon after the loop statement

```
for (int n = 0; n < 11; ++n);
```

So the loop does nothing

Also you are speaking about 10 elements that you need to read.

The code could look the following way:

```
const size_t N = 10;
vector<string> name_list( N );

for ( int n = 0; n < N; ++n )
{
    getline( cin, name_list[n] );
}

for ( vector<string>::size_type n = name_list.size(); n != 0; )
{
     cout << name_list[--n] << endl;
}
```

Also the same can be written with using standard algorithms. For example

```
const size_t N = 10;
vector<string> name_list;

name_list.reserve( N );

copy_n( istream_iterator<string>( cin ), N, back_inserter( name_list ) );

reverse_copy( name_list.begin(), name_list.end(), ostream_iterator<string>( cout, "\n" ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're asking, but I will take a step forward and assume you're having a problem with your code and need help repairing it.

The problem is simple. You've got a semicolon after the closing parenthesis of the `for()` loop. When I answered your previous sentence the only reason I put a semicolon after the for loop was because I didn't need to add anything to the for loop body. This is in contrast to your code in which you have `getline(cin, name_list[n])` which I presume to be a statement meant for the for loop body.

In that case you can't add a semicolon after the for loop. All it will do is run the for loop 11 times without executing any statements, then it will go on to the next line where it will read a line from `std::cin` into the first slot of the vector. This of course is not intended. And the solution is to remove the semicolon.

```c++
for (int n = 0; n < 11; ++n) // <-- semicolon gone
    std::getline(std::cin, name_list[n]);
```

I also see that you have semicolons after your `#include` statements. Those are also invalid, please remove them.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the semicolons

```
#include <iostream>;
                   ^
#include <vector>;
                 ^
#include <string>;
                 ^

for (int n = 0; n < 11; ++n);
                            ^
getline(cin, name_list[n]);
```

and all values will end in your vector. Note that after it you are printing only first value

```
cout << name_list[0];
```

Do it in loop to print full content:

```
for ( int i = name_list.size(); i--; )
{
     cout << name_list[i] << endl;
}
```